# JasperReport: continue on same while performing batch export

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am performing batch export in JaseReports with the codes below:

```
JRExporter e = new JRPdfExporter();
e.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT_LIST, jasperPrints);
e.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, outStream);
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test.pdf");
e.exportReport();
```

It exports successfully but each "merged pdf" on a separate page.
I'd like to have each merged page continually and not on a separate page. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Since you like to keep page layout, you can't not uss the `isIgnorePagination="true"` (it creates a continues layout), AFIK there is no settings on `JRPdfExporter` to not consider the single `JasperPrint`s as individuale pages.

The solution that you have are:

1. Creating a **main report** a new jrxml and include your .jasper in this as subreports. This was you could control the page breaks in your main report jrxml.
2. **Elaborate** your List of `JasperPrint`'s in code, moving all components into a single `JasperPrint`, determining if they should be on current page or added to new page, this method is fairly complex so I strongly suggest the first method.

**BTW**: Your are using deprecated code, the current version of code should be

```
JRExporter e = new JRPdfExporter();
exporter.setExporterInput(SimpleExporterInput.getInstance(jasperPrints));
exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(outStrem));
SimplePdfExporterConfiguration configuration = new SimplePdfExporterConfiguration();
configuration.setMetadataAuthor("n1ckgun"); // set you configs
exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test.pdf");
exporter.exportReport();
```

Comment: isIgnorePagination="true" would not make any difference unfortunately. Still the jasper would display each merged report in a separate page where the intention is the new merged jasper to continue in the same page as long as it has space

Comment: @n1ckgun Do you like to have continues layout in pdf (hence no pages) or do you just like try to control what ends up on what page?, still have pages?

Comment: I want to control what ends up on what page.
I have multiple jasper prints where each contains tables. When I export it, each merged jasper appears in a separate page but it has space to continue in the same page. After the first jasperprint exported, the second should not go to next page but continue from the same page of first jasper

Comment: However you still have page breaks correct?, hence you do not like a continues document without any pages? or is a continues doc ok?

Comment: I want to avoid the page break when it's merged. The merged table should go next to the table of prior jasper and not create a new page

Comment: I'm not explaining myself good enough, there is a big difference from having pages and not having pages... hence in continues layout there are no pages... just one very long page, my question is: Is continues layout ok?

Comment: sorry I misunderstood. I want to keep paging. No continuous layout

Comment: Ok, then you need to do something completely different... you can't add reports, like this. I will modify my answer.

Comment: @n1ckgun I have updated answer, you can't achieve what you need simple by passing the list (you would need to override the exporter and this is not the easiest task). I would suggest you do a main report file and include all your reports as subreports.